# How to cycle through all my variables

Tags: code-request

I have the following set of conditions for `p[i]`'s and defined a function `L` in terms of the `p[i]`, `i = 1,2,3,...,15`.

```
p[4] = A - p[1]

p[5] = B - p[1]

p[7] = C - (p[1] + p[4] + p[2] + p[14])

p[8] = D - (p[1] + p[4] + p[3] + p[15])

p[9] = E - (p[1] + p[2] + p[5] + p[15])

p[10] = F - (p[1] + p[3] + p[5] + p[14])

p[11] = G - (p[1] + p[4] + p[5] + p[13])

p[12] = 1 - (p[1] + p[2] + p[3] + p[4] + p[5] + p[6] + p[7] + p[8] + 
    p[9] + p[10] + p[11] + p[13] + p[14] + p[15])

L = Sum[n[i]*Log[p[i]], {i, 15}]
```

Note: `A`,`B`,`C`,`D`,`E`,`F`,`G` are constants.

With this, I can rewrite `L` in terms of `p[1]`, `p[2]`, `p[3]`, `p[6]`, `p[13]`, `p[14]`, `p[15]`.

I want to consider other ways of rewriting `L`, i.e., `L` in terms of other combinations of `p[i]`.
How can I set up the code in Mathematica?

Comment: First, do not use capital single letter variable names - several of them have a built-in meaning (such as `C`,`D`,`E` in your code). For the actual question, I'm not 100% what you're after. But if I understand correctly, you can try to use `Reduce` and pass all your relations as equations.

Comment: For instance, I could swap the first line of code to become p[1] = A - p[4] and then I'll be able to write L in terms of p[4] instead of p[1]. After reduction, L will be written in terms of 7 such p[i]'s because there are 15 unknowns and 8 conditions. I want to see the form that L takes for all possible choices of p[i], ie to say 15 choose 7 such choices.